# Java code for generating 16bit DMX values using sine and cosine

Tags: java

This is my try, based on good inputs from different places.
I ended up saving the [DMX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMX512)-values in two arrays (one for sine and one for cosine) as I guess that will make stuff easier later on when I want to add offset (and so on) to the lamps receiving the dmx-values.

This how I declare the two arrays and how the code is saving dmx-values in the two arrays:

```
int[] sineValues = new int[(360 * 1000) + 1];
int[] coSineValues = new int[(360 * 1000) + 1];

  public void generateSineValuesInArray() {

        int y = 0;

        for (double x = 0; x <= 360; x = x + 0.001) {

            double degrees = x;
            double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
            double sine = Math.sin(radians);

            sineValues[y] = (int) ((sine * 127) * 255) + (127 * 255);

            y++;

        }

    }

    public void generateCosineValuesInArray() {

        int y = 0;

        for (double x = 0; x <= 360; x = x + 0.001) {

            double degrees = x;
            double radians = Math.toRadians(degrees);
            double sine = Math.cos(radians);

            coSineValues[y] = (int) ((sine * 127) * 255) + (127 * 255);

            y++;

        }

    }
```

Yes, many elements in the two arrays and very small (0.001) increments in the two loops but that is what I found out was working best for getting a resolution that can do the dmx-fine so I can achieve smooth movements even at very low speeds.

This is the code for getting and sending the actual dmx-values:

```
public void doMovement() {

        valFromArrayPan = sineValues[counter];
        valFromArrayTilt = coSineValues[counter];

        coarsePan = (valFromArrayPan >> 8) & 255;
        finePan = valFromArrayPan & 255;
        coarseTilt = (valFromArrayTilt >> 8) & 255;
        fineTilt = valFromArrayTilt & 255;

        //Send dmx-values

        counter++;

        if (counter == sineValues.length) {

            counter = 1;

        }

    }
```

This is the code and what I do for running the movement:

```
    SineMovement SineMovement = new SineMovement();

    SineMovement.generateSineValuesInArray();
    SineMovement.generateCosineValuesInArray();

    speed =   20000000; //Slow speed
  
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(SineMovement::doMovement, 0, speed, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
```

I have tested above with a "real" 16bit moving head and I think, overall, it is working as I want it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Initialization

First about your idea of storing the precalculated values for sine and cosine: this is OK, and done for many different applications. But the way you initialize those arrays seems a bit complicated:

1. I would use just one loop for sine and cosine
2. You should never compare a floating point number with an == or similar, as there is a chance that this never will be true due to rounding errors. In your case the `<= 360` is not necessary at all and can be replaced by a `< 360` without doubt because sin(0°) is the same as sine(360°)
3. I would not use the angle as loop counter at all - you have a nice index in the array that you want to fill, so instead use the array index as loop counter and calculate your angle from it. This way you also don't have to fiddle with degrees to radian conversion.
4. You can make the tables and their initialization `static` because the sine and cosine tables will never change, no matter how often you load that class. And it's good practise to minimize visibility, and you never need to exchange the array, so set it `private static final` and use a static initializer.
5. Naming conventions say that you should name `static final` fields in ALL_UPPER_SNAKE_CASE.
6. As long as you do double calculations, use only double literals (= add a .0 to numbers if you don't have any other decimal places) to help the compiler in optimizing the code.

Summary: I would do the initialization like this:

```java
private static final int[] SIN_TABLE = new int[(360 * 1000) + 1];
private static final int[] COS_TABLE = new int[(360 * 1000) + 1];
private static final double INDEX_RAD_FACTOR = 2 * Math.PI / sineValues.length;
private static final double STRETCH_SIN = 127.0 * 255.0;

static {
    for (int x = 0; x < sineValues.length; x++) {
        double radians = x * INDEX_RAD_FACTOR;
        double sine = Math.sin(radians);
        SIN_TABLE[x] = (int) (Math.sin(radians) * STRETCH_SIN + STRETCH_SIN);
        COS_TABLE[x] = (int) (Math.cos(radians) * STRETCH_SIN + STRETCH_SIN);
    }
}
```

## Ongoing movement

### repeated calculation

You should create a private method for the splitting of the high and low byte as you use it multiple times.

```
private int[] splitInt(int toSplit) {
  int[] result = new byte[2];
  result[0] = toSplit & 255;
  result[1] = (toSplit >> 8) & 255;
  return result;
}
```

Instead of an `int` you could also use a `short`, but don't use a `byte` because all of that datatypes are signed and `byte` goes from -128 to +127.

### timing relevant code

Also as you are working with stuff that needs exact timing, I would not use an if in that method - the case where the condition is `true` and where it's not, could take a different amount of time and therefore create a weird pause if your application requires short execution times (when the "speed" is not slow, but fast). Also you should start `counter` with and reset it to 0 all the time - arrays are 0-based in Java.

```java
private int counter = 0;

public void doMovement() {
    int[] overallPan = splitInt(SIN_TABLE[counter]);
    int[] overallTilt = splitInt(COS_TABLE[counter]);

    int coarsePan = overallPan[1];
    int finePan = overallPan[0];
    int coarseTilt = overallTilt[1]
    int fineTilt = overallTilt[0];

    // TODO: Send dmx-values

    counter = (counter + 1) % SIN_TABLE.length;
}
```

## Starting

The starting of your timed code looks quite good, with the above changes to the initialization you do no longer have to call the initialization of sine and cosine tables manually.

And I would not use nanoseconds as time unit, probably your code wouldn't be fast enough to be called that often, and also with 360000 possible steps in the sine curve, even with a microsecond resolution you would only need one third of a second to have set all possible values. Probably even that is too fast to be visible. I would not go just millisecond resolution, because then all values would need 6 minutes to be shown and thats probably to slow.

Again if `speed` is a `long` variable it deserves to be initialized with a `long` literal to help the compiler in optimization, this is denoted by an `L` at the end of the number. (And I divided the value you gave by 1000 because I reduced the resolution to microseconds.)

````java
SineMovement SineMovement = new SineMovement();

long speed = 20000L; //Slow speed
  
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(SineMovement::doMovement, 0L, speed, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS);
```
````

Comment: Wow, this is just perfect! I forgot to add the tag #beginner as this is my first project in Java and I must say that your reply really learned me a lot! I like the way you do your stuff, very informative and kind, are you a teacher? :)

Comment: No, I'm a professional developer and "Scrum master", but it's not the first time that I did code reviews for others (mostly in my team) - sometimes I even earn money just with reviewing code ;-) Also I like to analyse other developers code and I'm in the business for quite a while now (> 30 years)